# get email address from qshape defeffered queue

Tags: postfix, email-server

Hi to everyone like in the title,
I would like to know how to get the email address from the **qshape deferred queue**
because I have checked the

> /var/spool/postfix/deferred

directory and obviously 
the messages are listed by **ID message**.
I was thinking to use mailq command and then retrieve the email address with some script
but if there is same tool that already to this I really appreciate it.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

try running [postcat](http://www.postfix.org/postcat.1.html) on actual file containing the message. viewing with any text editor should work too.

Comment: I didn't know this command nice one, but I have more than 50k deferred mail so what you suggest to get all the 50k email address?

Comment: @marcodv - i'm affraid you'll have to do some scripting